# Twisted - Close websocket properly with free up specific port

Tags: python, websocket, twisted

At the moment i'm working with twisted in python. How can I close the websocket instance properly when the program exits. Just "reactor.stop" won't do the job.
Here's the code:

```
class MyWebSocketProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
def onConnect(self, request):
    self.log("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

def onOpen(self):
    self.log("WebSocket connection open.")

def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    if payload == "bandwidth":
        content = json.dumps(NetworkMessages.data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
        self.sendMessage(content)
        self.log("Sent: {}".format(content))
    else:
        self.log("Unknown request!")

def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
    self.log("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

def log(self, message):
    DataLogger.writeActualData(WebSocketServer.NAME, [message])


class WebSocketServer(object):
def __init__(self,reactor,address,port,dt,wifi):
    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(address)
    factory.protocol = MyWebSocketProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)
```

Comment: That's an OS related thing. When the listening process stops, the socket is freed by the OS. You should use netstat or a similar tool to see what process is still listening.

Comment: You could call ``self.transport.loseConnection()`` from within the protocol. This will disconnect the client.

Comment: @klaus-d Thank you! Can I control netstat with python? Force the OS to close a specific port?

Comment: @notorious-no That's not the problem. I want to close the websocket properly without any clients connected.